# How do I end this game when the user gets a question wrong?

Tags: java

I am doing an assignment for my Computer Programming course where I have chosen to do a Trivia game.  This game is on badminton.  I have made the game but I don't know how to end it.

For example, when the user gets one question wrong the game is supposed to end.  But in my code it prints out the next question.

Any ideas on what lines I can add or what changes need to be made?
Thanks

```
public class Trivia {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

        System.out.println("Here are the game rules: ");
        System.out.println("1. You do not have any power ups to use");
        System.out.println("2. You may only get one question wrong");
        System.out.println("3.If you get any question wrong, you will get what you win, and the game will end");
        System.out.println("Try your best to answer the questions");
        System.out.println("Type Start to begin");

        String start = input.next();
        String word = null;

        if (start.equalsIgnoreCase("Start")) {
            Questions(word);
        }
    }
    public static void Questions(String word) {
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
        int total;
        int a = 500;
        int b = 850;
        int c = 1000;
        int d = 1250;
        int e = 1850;
        int f = 2000;
        int g = 2500;
        int h = 3000;

        System.out.println("1. What is the maximum number of players that can play Badminton in one court?  Worth $500");
        String [] o = {"A: 1", "B: 3", "C: 4"};
        System.out.printf("%4s %10s %10s\n", o);

        String q1 = input.next();

        if (q1.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
            System.out.println("Your answer is correct!  You won $500");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Game over! Try again next time");
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("2. In doubles play, the first serve for the serving side begins in what court?  Worth $850");
        String [] q2 = {"A: Right service of court", "B: Left service of court", "C: Either side"};
        System.out.printf("%4s %30s %20s\n", q2);

        String ans = input.next();

        if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
            System.out.println("Your answer is correct!  You won $850");
            total = a + b;
            System.out.println("Your total is: $" +total);
        }
        else {
            System.out.println("Game over! You won $500");
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("3. The game of badminton became popular in the United States during what time?  Worth $1000");
        String [] q3 = {"A: 1930", "B: 1830", "C: 1500"};
        System.out.printf("%4s %30s %20s\n", q3);

        String ans3 = input.next();

        if (ans3.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
            System.out.println("Your answer is correct!  You won $1000");
            total = a + b + c;
            System.out.println("Your total is: $" +total);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Game over! You won $1350");
        }

        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("4. During the game, may you hit the shuttle two times in a row?  Woth $1250");
        String [] q4 = {"A: Yes", "B: No", "C: Both A and B"};
        System.out.printf("%4s %10s %18s\n", q4);

        String ans4 = input.next();

        if (ans4.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
            System.out.println("Your answer is correct!  You won $1250");
            total = a + b + c + d;
            System.out.println("Your total is: $" +total);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Game over! You won $2350");
        }
```

Comment: As your logic, you have to place each if else statement inside their previous success condition. otherwise your logic will print everything one by one. But it is really a nasty approach. if you have more questions, then you will have endless nested loops.

Comment: Put a return statement after the println showing that the game is over.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply put return statement in every else condition.

```
else{
      System.out.println("Game over! Try again next time");
      return;
}
```

Hope that helps..!!

Answer (score 0):

That's not the best way, exactly. But you need totally change your code to make it more simple. But for your case you can make so:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

    public class tets {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("Here are the game rules: ");
            System.out.println("1. You do not have any power ups to use");
            System.out.println("2. You may only get one question wrong");
            System.out.println("3.If you get any question wrong, you will get what you win, and the game will end");
            System.out.println("Try your best to answer the questions");
            System.out.println("Type Start to begin");
            String start = input.next();
            String word = null;
            if (start.equalsIgnoreCase("Start")) {
                Questions(word);
            }
        }

        public static void Questions(String word) {
            boolean isGame = true;
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            int total;
            int a = 500;
            int b = 850;
            int c = 1000;
            int d = 1250;
            int e = 1850;
            int f = 2000;
            int g = 2500;
            int h = 3000;
            System.out.println("1. What is the maximum number of players that can play Badminton in one court?  Worth $500");
            String[] o = {"A: 1", "B: 3", "C: 4"};
            System.out.printf("%4s %10s %10s\n", o);
            String q1 = input.next();

                if (q1.equalsIgnoreCase("C")) {
                    System.out.println("Your answer is correct!  You won $500");
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Game over! Try again next time");
                    isGame = false;
                }
                System.out.println();
                if (isGame) {
                System.out.println("2. In doubles play, the first serve for the serving side begins in what court?  Worth $850");
                String[] q2 = {"A: Right service of court", "B: Left service of court", "C: Either side"};
                System.out.printf("%4s %30s %20s\n", q2);
                String ans = input.next();
                    if (ans.equalsIgnoreCase("A")) {
                        System.out.println("Your answer is correct!  You won $850");
                        total = a + b;
                        System.out.println("Your total is: $" + total);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Game over! You won $500");
                        isGame = false;
                    }
                }
                if (isGame) {
                    System.out.println();
                    System.out.println("3. The game of badminton became popular in the United States during what time?  Worth $1000");
                    String[] q3 = {"A: 1930", "B: 1830", "C: 1500"};
                    System.out.printf("%4s %30s %20s\n", q3);
                    String ans3 = input.next();
                    if (ans3.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                        System.out.println("Your answer is correct!  You won $1000");
                        total = a + b + c;
                        System.out.println("Your total is: $" + total);
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("Game over! You won $1350");
                        isGame = false;
                    }
                }
            if (isGame) {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println("4. During the game, may you hit the shuttle two times in a row?  Woth $1250");
                String[] q4 = {"A: Yes", "B: No", "C: Both A and B"};
                System.out.printf("%4s %10s %18s\n", q4);
                String ans4 = input.next();
                if (ans4.equalsIgnoreCase("B")) {
                    System.out.println("Your answer is correct!  You won $1250");
                    total = a + b + c + d;
                    System.out.println("Your total is: $" + total);
                } else {
                    System.out.println("Game over! You won $2350");
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

But think about better code. Make some methods, give more rational and more readable names for your variables.

For example for checking wrong answer you can make method:

```
boolean isCorrectAnswer(String answer, String correctAnswer){
    return answer.equals(correctAnswer);
}
```

Hope that helps you!

Comment: Thanks, this solution works but requires a little bit of effort.